# Using Java 8 functions instead of multiple if elses

Tags: java, java-8

I have below code, getBrand and calculateSum are some function that return value. I would like to compact this code using java 8 functions. I would like to get rid of multiple if's if possible. Is it possible using Java 8 functions?

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Q56068628 {

    static class Brand {
        public Set<Location> locations() { return Collections.emptySet(); }
    }
    static class Location {}
    static class Product {}

    int getSum(int price, Product p){
        int sum = 0;
        if(price > 0){
           Brand b = getBrand(p); // getBrand takes type Product as argument
           if( b !=null){
              Set<Location> s = new HashSet<>();
              s.addAll(b.locations());
              for(Location l : s){
                sum = calculateSum(l, sum); /* calculateSum function takes location
                            argument and calculates sum. Sum value is replaced for
                          each for loop call */
              }
           }
        }
       return sum;
    }

    private Brand getBrand(Product p ){
    //// some code returns brand
        return null;
    }

     private int calculateSum(Location l, int sum ){
        //// some code returns an integer
        return 0;
     }

}
```

Comment: If all you require is the `sum` using the last location, why iterate through the whole collection? And why are you passing `sum` to `calculateSum`,  when it's being replaced in every loop.

Answer (score 0):

It probably is, but an `if` statement is usually cheaper than a method call, plus it's easier for people who don't know those APIs to read. One improvement you could consider is this:

```
private Optional<Brand> getBrand(Product p ){
   //...
   //something...
   if (condition) { return Optional.ofNullable(new Brand(p)); }
   else { return Optional.empty(); }
}
```

Then:

```
Optional<Brand> brand = getBrand(p);
if (brand.isPresent()) {
  Brand b = brand.get();
}
```

Much safer on the null handling.

Comment: That leaves even more `if`s than before. Why not use `ifPresent` with a `Consumer` instead of the if statement around `isPresent`?